# Laravel 5.5 validator

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Is there a way in laravel on how I can choose an email that is stored in the database?

For example, if I want a unique email, you use "unique:users" like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required'
        ]);
```

But what I want to know is if it can check if the given email is stored in the database or not. Is it possible to do this with the validator?

Comment: That's exactly what the unique validator does, it fails if the email already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-exists) key word as :

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => 'required|unique:users|exists:users',
    'password' => 'required'
]);
```

Or you can do something like that :

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => 'required|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    echo 'That email address is already registered';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure it doesn't exist in DB, use the [`unique`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique) rule:

```
unique:table
```

If you want to be sure the record exists in DB, use the [`exists`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-exists) rule:

```
exists:table
```